# Project Reduplication of Deduplication Has Begun!

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, se-quality-project

While [announcing the second iteration of the Stack Exchange quality project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project), I not-so-briefly alluded to a collaboration we're kicking off with the University Of Melbourne.

The project presents some very interesting possibilities for us if their model validates as well as is hoped:

- Knowing very quickly if a question is *not* a duplicate
- Being able to quickly surface the most appropriate (by criteria we provide) duplicate with a high degree of accuracy.
- Being able to surface high *and* low quality groups of questions that essentially ask the same thing that aren't currently being surfaced very well

Essentially, we might to be able to alleviate two of the most frequent pain points for new and experienced users alike:

- By showing more relevant probable duplicates while folks ask, we should stand to lessen the frequency of duplicate questions (particularly, those that tend to be of not-so-great quality)
- We might be in a better position to more clearly identify something  as *not* a duplicate, which could ease *those mean jerks closed my question as a duplicate and it completely wasn't!*

The [paper describing the methodology](http://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/tbaldwin/pubs/sigir2016-webqa.pdf) is short and worth reading if you're curious.

#### So, what do we need from you?

The researchers have already validated data in subject domains where they're knowledgeable enough to make a clear call on something being a duplicate or not. However, we cover a pretty vast group of academic and technical domains, and they simply need knowledgeable people from those communities to help them decide if their method made the right decision.

#### How are we going to do this?

Easily. They've built a system similar to our review system where you're presented with a pair of questions, and can indicate if they're a duplicate, strongly related, or not a duplicate. You can use your Stack Exchange account to sign in.

#### Who is eligible?

Those with the ability to cast close votes on:

- Android
- English Language & Usage
- GIS
- Mathematica
- Physics
- Software Engineering
- Stats
- Tex
- Unix & Linux
- Webmasters
- Wordpress

In the *rare* cases where you have a gold tag badge, but have not yet unlocked close privileges, a gold tag badge will allow you to work on that subset of questions.

#### What about other sites? What about Stack Overflow?

We'll have to see how things go with this initial set. If everything looks really promising, then they'll take a look at running Stack Overflow through the model. That would be an *enormous* undertaking since it would entail every single question since the dawn of time, while accounting for duplicate targets being deleted later.

There might also be a need to run a few more smaller sites through - we just have to see how it goes.

#### Where do we go from here?

Look for a post on your meta site from Doris Hoogeveen letting folks know that we're ready for help if you care to provide it. She'll link to this post for the benefit of folks that missed it.

#### What if it doesn't pan out?

We're okay with that because we learn quite a bit either way. It's my personal opinion that getting the right duplicates in front of people as they ask is probably the most impactful way that we can elevate the experience of both new and experienced users. If something looks promising in that direction, we feel it's worth exploring.

Comment: This is very, very cool.

Comment: Awesome. I wanted to sign in but I saw that neither Chem nor ELL are among the test sites. :/

Comment: @M.A.R. I'm quite certain Doris is going to be monitoring this for feedback / feature requests / etc - I'm not sure why Chemistry wasn't included because it is a great case site (possibly just resource constraints). If they end up needing more, I can't imagine them not considering it.

Comment: (gnat feverishly trying to find a duplicate of this very post)

Comment: As @hairboat said, this is very, very cool! I have a question about the cQA data itself. Either I'm not seeing it, or it's not mentioned in the paper, but does this use the public data dump and then annotate from that starting point, or is this using another set of data provided by Stack Exchange? I"m really just curious what the original source of the data is.

Comment: @Andy It's from our public dumps and API. They reached out to us only once they were pretty sure they had something.

Comment: "In the rare cases where you have a gold tag badge, but have not yet unlocked close privileges" does that even happen?

Comment: @Cai I dunno if there's a recorded case or not but you'd basically have to lose about 7000 reputation minimum to the rep cap, is how it'd happen.

Comment: @Cai It has happened in cases where we split sites, or bulk migrations ran, or a bunch of stuff was disassociated - I think we pretty much have all of those edge cases worked out now, but it has happened.

Comment: aww yeah this sounds super awesome!

Comment: @gnat I have two duplicates of this very Post. They are ages 11 and 2.

Comment: @TimPost Are they really duplicates or just strongly related?

Comment: @Cai Could be someone who gave a lot of bounties.

Comment: Why isn't this [tag:featured]?

Comment: Tim, but we generally don't close older Posts as duplicates of younger ones

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to get the actual methodology they used to conduct this experiment? The paper mainly seems to detail the results and not how they found those results.

Comment: The paper is a very interesting read, curious to see how this pans out on a larger scale and for real-time suggestions

Comment: I don't see anywhere I can log in for this.  Am I missing something?  (I have the required rep on U&L.)

Comment: @Wildcard "Look for a post on your meta site from Doris Hoogeveen letting folks know that *we're ready for help* if you care to provide it."

Comment: @TimPost Is it actually possible to have a gold badge without having 3k rep? The only way I could think of would be if that user gave away 8k+ rep in bounties.

Comment: If someone’s questions is answered by a few “closely related” questions that the system can automatically show, should there be a new close reason of “Read the side bar!”.
We get so many questions that have 2 or more issues the persons does not understand, yet each issue is already covered well by anther question.

Comment: We haven't seen a meta post for this on WordPress yet, so I've started it [here](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4295/project-reduplication-of-deduplication).

Comment: This sounds neat? Will there be any possible support for, say, giving SE a question and having the algorithm find relevant posts? (YMMV when using Google.)

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm Doris. Several people have asked about site they would like to annotate for, but we have limited the project to the twelve largest sites after StackOverflow for now. Unfortunately Chem and ELL are not part of these twelve sites, but U&L is. We started with four sites as a pilot study, to get some feedback and improve the interface, before moving to the other ones, but I am about to post on the meta forums of all twelve sites. Thanks to everyone who participated so far!

Comment: The twelve sites are: Android Enthusiasts, TeX - LaTeX, Arqade, Software Engineering, English Language & Usage, Unix & Linux, Physics, Geographic Information Systems, Mathematica, Cross Validated, Webmasters, and WordPress Development.

Comment: @gnat [Yes we do.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/86997?page=28&sort=newest)

Answer (score 8):

Thinking about Stack Overflow…

Does the learning system need to consider it as one site, or can for example the PHP tag be done in isolation?

Likewise we can define collection of tags, C#,VB.NET,.NET, ASP.NET for example that have few questions outside of the “tag group” and lots of questions crossing tags within the group.   Then just look for duplications within the given group.

Comment: I believe it's going to need to work in a similar manner as our tag prediction engine - as soon as it can begin to hazard a guess about what you're talking about, it'll infer tags, and start looking. It kind of has to work that way because in the absence of code, a question asking how to connect to a database would be remarkably similar between C# and PHP. But the cool part is once we have the data sets validated, they can start trying all sorts of things with the model since they'll have 'known correct' outcomes they can measure against.

Answer (score -2):

I just posted my concerns about this on [stats.stackexchage](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/project-reduplication-of-deduplication-cross-validated/4487#4487), so I will follow up with a summary here:
I am really concerned that this will prevent people from asking questions or getting help on stack exchange.  Here are my reasons:

1. **Synthesis Questions:** I am worried that project  will limit sythensis questions, which are re-asked questions for the purpose of getting a final answer.  Usually these are asked when the original question: 1) has multiple answer that changed over the years or 2) It has had conflicting answers over years
2. **Potential for Over-fitting** The unstructured data from stack exchange posts is prone to overfitting and we have to be careful of that.
3. **Skewed toward/against the questions of new users**: Depending on how you code it the algorithm is going to be skewed toward or against news users in a significant way.

   > 1. [Reason for the Skew Against] Basically new users are prone toward producing missing values this text mined dataset then older users because reputation system promotes such behavior.
   > 2. [Reason for the Skew Toward] On the other hand, new users are less familiar with the site are more prone not to be familar with how to navigate stack exchange and thus will ask duplicated questions.
4. **StackOverflow will be an outlier**:  This will be either very good or very bad for stackoverflow because: 1) To ask how code something means there are at least 5 valid duplicates of how to code in other languages.  2) The dependency on tags as classifier, cluster, or filter of question @IanRingrose mentioned.

The duplicate questions tag does not automatically delete questions.  I am worried that this safe guard from duplicate questions tag will be removed when one releases Project Reduplication of Deduplication into the full wild of stack exchange.  Again, I explain each of these reasons in more detail in the link below.

P.S. Also I just posted an example of reason 1.2 (Synthesis Question) in Cross Validated

Comment: I'm not convinced synthesis questions should ever be asked in the first place. If the question has lousy answers (conflicting and non-authoritative, changing, missing, wrong), then the correct way to fix it is to either make a useful edit in order to bump and give additional details, or add a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties).