# Leave closed question standing and submit new on-topic version or edit closed question and vote for reopening?

Tags: discussion

The question [What supplement is most chemically similar to chamomile?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24904/7951) was posed in MedicalSciences.SE and was subsequently closed for [personal medical advice](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/7951).

2 days later, [Active ingredient of Chamomile](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24920/7951) was posted by the same person.

Both questions ask about the same thing and so I commented on this in the second question linking to the first so both were linked together in MedicalSciences.SE.

In response I was told that:

> I think this is a (rare) example of a closed question resubmitted in acceptable form (after the edits). I don't think it can be answered, but I don't think it's off topic either.

This got me thinking what might be the best approach. I could have asked this in [MedicalSciences.SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), but this is a question which affects all StackExchange sites.

- Is it best to leave the original question as-is with the closure and reason (to highlight more to others that these questions will be closed) then submit an on-topic version?

  One problem with this as I have seen on some stacks is that the closed question can lead to massive numbers of downvotes detrimental to the OP's reputation score.

**or**

- Is it best to edit the closed question and ask for reopening (to reduce number of closed questions and help with a tidy stack of questions and answers)?

Comment: I think it's best to ask this on [Medical Science's own meta](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Usually it is best to close a new version of an older question as duplicate. They should generally edit the older question.

Comment: Here's what to do when a question is closed and you want it reopened, which is the same across sites: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions. Note that it doesn't say anything at all about just posting a new question. But the close notices do say to post a new one, it has led to friction in the past: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951/369802. I think this user saw something similar and as such may have reposted instead of edited.

Answer (score 3):

If you are thinking about asking the same question as an existing one then I think you should always resist that temptation.

Instead, if the original question is closed, then edit to improve it and vote or flag to have it reviewed for re-opening, if that does not appear to be triggered by the edit.

Comment: The edit itself should nominate it for re-opening. It will get inserted into the reopen queue. So make sure that your first edit counts in that respect, as you only get added to the queue once.