# Please tweak the behavior of the dupe "does this answer your question?" message so it does not suck

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, user-interface, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I have no problem with my question being closed as a dupe; hey, I got an answer! Yet, the way the "Does this answer your question" message works is not great at all. Let me explain.

1. I post the question -- I have a problem to solve
2. Someone *thinks* it's a duplicate, they flag it, and the message pops up.
3. I get notified and duly go to check whether the other question is, indeed, a dupe
4. It takes me a couple of minutes to *check* that it's a dupe (read the answer, try the solution, run the tests)
5. Other users in the meantime VTC without checking, so they close the question at light speed. Bless them.
6. I go back to the question tab to vote, "yes," as the dupe answers the question
7. I have to "sadomasochistically" press "*Submit*." What's wrong with using "Yes" and "No" buttons and better terminology?
8. I get punished by a "The question is already closed" message. I go from being happy I found a solution to being upset that my question is closed, without my input, and that somehow I did something incorrect by trying to help the system by voting.
9. The system suggests I delete my question. Thanks, but I'm not deleting something I put some effort in; too bad you don't value it.
10. The spinner gets stuck forever

[image]

Please fix this interaction:

- remove the Submit button in favor of Yes and No or, at least, [change the word so it explains what happens next](https://uxmovement.com/forms/why-your-form-buttons-should-never-say-submit/)
- [Radio buttons for a yes/no questions are to improve](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61309/radio-button-yes-no-or-no-yes#61313).
- don't blame *me* for trying to help with a [useless message](https://uxplanet.org/how-to-write-good-error-messages-858e4551cd4)
- fix the infinite spinner

Bonus content, the error is here:

[image]

in this case, `json.Success` should be set to true, so the page reloads, instead of sending the useless "the question has already been closed, sucker(*)" in `json.Message`

---

(*) it may, or may not, actually say "sucker," but it felt like it

Comment: "I get punished by a "The question is already closed" message. " - The closure of a question due to it being a duplicate is **NOT** a punishment.  "The system suggests I delete my question." - I actually find that hard to believe, and have never encountered that message, in my decade of using Stack Exchange communities.  Stretching the truth and/or reality is the reason I felt compelled to downvote this suggestion, even though I believe the behavior of a spinning circle, should be changed.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. We would rather copy-paste it directly into production ....

Comment: @Ramhound it's a punishment if it feels like it. I know it's not meant to, but that's the way it is... Also it was a pun on the S/M undertones of "submit" ;-)

Comment: @rene sorry, I forgot, but I don't have the original page open. Can I be excused?

Comment: @Sklivvz for once. And careful what you post, you might get hired ;)

Comment: Personally, requiring the "Submit" button in addition to "Yes" or "No" seems like a good thing - wouldn't want an accidental mis-click to close a Q, after all.

Comment: @bobble agreed but not "submit", perhaps "confirm"? "ok"?

Comment: @Ramhound The system suggesting to [delete and post a new question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349951/369802) is a bit of a problem... Perhaps write a few close-worthy posts? :D (also, these notices are just about two years old, so that decade won't help much)

Comment: "*remove the Submit button in favor of Yes and No*" alternative wording is preferred rather than removing it completely since there's a case for a question getting multiple duplicate suggestions.