# Can I no longer see who closed my question?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Some months ago, I could see who closed a question, but not anymore? I screenshot [How did "unless" semantically shift to signify "except if"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/545842).

[image]

Comment: Do you really need to know who voted to close the question? How that could help you to improve it?

Comment: This is answered in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/377214) to [How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/how-could-we-improve-our-planned-post-notice-improvements)

Comment: @Rubén Not necessarily. I was just worried that something was wrong with my browser or computer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The information can still be found, but it was hidden for a reason. Think carefully if you plan on using that information.

You can still see the list of close voters in the timeline (rewind clock icon under votes on the left) and the edit history, though the latter's not easy to access for unedited questions. The information is also available through other, less convenient avenues such as the API (and therefore the long-unmaintained apps) and SEDE. It might be additionally relevant to note that *other* high rep users (3k+ rep) can also see the names directly in the close notice.

There is [a reason for hiding this information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/how-could-we-improve-our-planned-post-notice-improvements/332502#comment1176342_332502):

> We have clear and scary examples of times when users lash out at specific closers because their question was closed or deleted. Up to and including requiring police intervention or having their employers called because of closing someone's question. This isn't OK. I'd much rather a user be angry at the system for closing their question than at a person.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with your browser, but seeing who voted to close your post could make the asker angry, illicit revenge-voting, etc. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/377214) answer here for the reasons why the ability to see that info was rescinded.

You can still see the close-voting info in the "Show vote summaries" tab in the timeline on the question, but please be careful with that information.