# Help Center documentation should be updated to reflect new procedures for closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, help-center

The Help Center page "[What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)" contains the following:

> If a moderator (user with a ♦ symbol after their name) closed the question, then you may flag it for moderator attention. Again, do this only after editing and include a detailed explanation of why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.

However, [the person who posted a closed question can no longer easily see who closed it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/630228), which was apparently a deliberate decision on the part of the Stack Exchange admins.

The help page currently suggests doing something which the admins have deliberately made not entirely easy to do. If in fact the admins want to steer new users away from seeing who closed their questions, then they should probably edit the Help Center page to avoid mentioning this possibility. If they think that the quoted point above is an important option for new users, then they should revert from the new policy linked above.

Comment: The first thing suggested - leaving a comment - actually does nothing toward getting the question seen by others in order to have it reopened. I'd remove that and make editing the top one, since that's "preferred" and does have an effect (most of the time). Also, the page doesn't say that you only need 250 reputation (not 3,000) if voting to reopen your *own* question.