# Display user reputation on mouseover for the list of the users who closed the question

Tags: feature-request, reputation, closed-questions, tooltips

Reputation should be displayed on mouseover for each of the users listed in the blue "Closed question" box. This box appears at the top of the closed question. This change will make the look and feel of the list of the users consistent with rest of the site. For example:

- Reputation and badges are displayed for the OP, for the users who answered the question, and for the users who edited the question or the answers.
- Reputation is displayed on mouseover for the users who commented on posts.

[image: Closed question box is displayed at the top of the OP]

**PROS:**

- The relatively unobtrusive mouseover rep gives a quick "intro", enabling one to see to what extent the user who closed the question is a "veteran" on the site. This is analogous to the rep displayed next to the user who asked/answered the question. One can learn a lot from occasionally following the profile link to high rep users, exploring their posts, etc.
- Additional information can be useful in ways that are hard to predict. Unfortunately, it is hard to quantify that before the change is done. One could do experiments to measure the improvement (if any) in questions reopened (or not) with *vs.* without the change implemented.

**CONS:**

- If you do not like rep displayed on mouseover, you have to make an effort to not accidentally move your mouse over the user name.
- The proposed change does nothing for those who access the site on a smartphone.
- For some users, the **only** desired places to display the rep is next to questions or answers, or on the user profile page. Even the mouseover of the rep for comments is not needed.

Comment: The users who closed the question are not displayed to the question author in the post notice. The close-voters are only displayed to users who have the close-vote privilege and who are not the question author. If someone else wants to know who voted to close, then they need to look in the question timeline or history.

Comment: @Makyen As you can see from the screenshot above, it says "Viewable by the post author and users with the close/reopen vote privilege". Is that a mistake, and the question author in fact cannot see the list of the users who closed the question (= blue box screenshot)?

Comment: Yes, that statement in the post notice is not accurate. Please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332502/271271) announcing the removal of the close voters from the view which is shown to the question author (starting on 2020-07-22). Note that the close voters are not displayed in the post notice to the question author, even if the question author is a moderator on the site.

Comment: @Makyen Big thank you for the link and the explanation! Does it make sense to ask in a *separate* question to sync the post notice to reflect the reality? This new reality BTW makes my **current** question much less useful... :)

Comment: You're welcome to ask a question for that. IIRC, there's either an existing question or an answer on the announcement question for post notices. I'd have to check to see where/if such exists, but just going ahead and asking is certainly an option. Worst case is it gets closed as a duplicate. IMO, the text about "viewable by the post author and users..." really should be reworded. What's shown to the post owner vs what's shown to close-vote privileged users are *definitely* defined separately (i.e. moderators can see (and sort-of change) those separate entries for site specific close reasons).

Comment: "One can learn a lot from occasionally following the profile link to high rep users, exploring their posts, etc." - This sounds like the type of behavior that leads to revenge downvoting, and stalking another user's contributions looking for tiniest reason to downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound If anything, it led to upvotes, since I explored other answers by these high rep users. I also learned a lot of useful info from these answers.

Comment: Stalking other user's contributions and giving them upvotes could be considered even worse than issuing downvotes.  It would be considered serial voting in either case it was a continuous pattern.  Having lost hundreds of reputation points from serial downvoting I am incredibly sensitive to serial voting in general.

Comment: @Ramhound As long as it is normal exploring of questions and answers and learning, and occasional upvoting or downvoting, and not stalking or serial upvoting or serial downvoting, there is **nothing** wrong with it. **I am not advocating stalking users. I am not advocating serial upvoting and serial downvoting.**

Answer (score 14):

> Reputation should be displayed on mouseover for each of the users listed in the blue "Closed question" box

**Why**? What are the benefits of this?

I don't think that "make the look and feel of the list of the users consistent with rest of the site" is good enough reason:

- In most places it's showing the reputation alongside the name, not as tooltip.
- In comments, where it's indeed a tooltip, it's not really useful and if anything, I'd support request asking to remove the reputation tooltip from there, not the other way around.

Comment: Is there anywhere where the rep and/or badges **are** useful to display, and why?

Comment: @Timur in posts, yes, to give quick introduction of the user. When you read question or answer by someone, it's useful to see how "veteran" they are on the site. But it's less relevant in case of question closure: the fact they could close means they're veteran and/or moderators, that's enough info.

Answer (score 8):

Dubious UX unification points *aside*...

> The OP can better estimate the chances of being able to edit and then reopen the question. A question closed by 3 high rep users is different from a question closed by 3 low rep users.

There is no material difference via reputation in who closes a question.  Users are vanishingly unlikely to return to a closed question, full stop, since they aren't notified when the question is updated or edited.

...and they shouldn't have to be.  The question goes into the Review Queues for *others* to then review it to see if it's been improved enough to reopen.

Appealing to the people that closed the question is exactly the wrong way to go when fixing a closed question.

> The relatively unobtrusive mouseover rep gives a quick "intro", enabling one to see to what extent the user who closed the question is a "veteran" on the site. This is analogous to the rep displayed next to the user who asked/answered the question. One can learn a lot from occasionally following the profile link to high rep users, exploring their posts, etc.

I use my phone a lot.  I don't get mouseover text on my phone.  The metadata on who closed a question when looking at it on my phone doesn't help me out in the context of looking at it on a phone, when I'm probably just idly looking at questions about topics I'm interested in and trying to see what others replies were.

On desktop the argument is stronger.  When I'm using Stack Overflow at work, I really don't care who closed a question; I want to see if the material in the question is still salvageable enough for me to get an answer out of it.  (If I could, then I'd probably cast a reopen vote for it.)

> Additional information can be useful in ways that are hard to predict.

Quantify this.  I come from a world where *too much* information can be detrimental to the experience.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there anywhere on the site where the rep is in fact useful to display? And if yes, why?

Comment: Maybe as a part of the question/answer signature as it's always done now, and in the stats pages of a person's profile page.  The signature gives you some (sometimes false) sense of security in that the person may know what they're talking about, but beyond that, I couldn't see anywhere else to put it.  The privilege to close or take certain moderation actions happens at specific rep levels, so one can always be assured that they have *at least* X rep when looking in those other circumstances.