# Why can't I see who voted to close my question?

Tags: support, bug, closed-questions, privileges

Normally users with the close/reopen votes privilege can see who voted to close a question.

[image: Duplicate notice with list of users]

However, when I check [a closed question I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50065643/3357935) I can't see who voted to close it.

[image: Closed notice without list of users]

I thought I recalled being able to view who closed my question in the past. Was this an intentional change? Or have close votes always been hidden when looking at your own question?

Comment: Can you see it in the post history when you click the "activity" button under the voting buttons? I don't see it in the post notice on a question I had closed as a duplicate, but I can see it in the history.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/how-could-we-improve-our-planned-post-notice-improvements) - in particular, its currently accepted [answer](/a/332502) states "We've changed the post notices for question askers so that they do not see the usernames of close voters listed - this includes askers with the close/reopen vote privilege". FYI, I found the post link in the 2020-07-22 update statement in this system recent changes [answer](/a/342029).

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, I can see close votes in both the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50065643/timeline) and [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50065643/revisions).

Comment: @Glorfindel FYI, I've found an answer, in my proposed duplicate question, which explains about removing those notices. , Note that answer was updated on July 22, 2020 by kristinalustig to change the tag from "status-planned" to "status-completed", and to add an initial update text stating that the change has now been made.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for refreshing my memory :)

Comment: @JohnOmielan That answer does answer my question, but I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate. The linked question is open-ended and does not mention close votes.