# Can users with a gold tag badge but not enough reputation to vote to close use their immediate duplicate closing powers?

Tags: support, reputation, dupehammer

It's possible for users to have a gold tag badge but not have enough reputation to vote to close, such as if they've given away most of their rep in bounties, or if they started off posting a lot of highly-voted answers but hit the reputation cap, preventing them from earning most of the rep from upvotes and making them stop short of the required 3,000 reputation (out of 10,000, or 10 rep per upvote times 1,000 required upvotes for the badge).

Can such a user single-handedly close questions as duplicates? If they attempt to cast a recommend closure flag as a duplicate, will it be remapped to an immediate closure? Also, can such users use their immediate *reopening* powers?

**Update:** After randomly clicking on some posts, I happened to stumble upon [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286329/project-reduplication-of-deduplication-has-begun?) that states the following:

> In the rare cases where you have a gold tag badge, but have not yet unlocked close privileges, a gold tag badge will allow you to work on that subset of questions.

Is this still the case today?

Comment: you also need at least 200 upvoted answers, i.e. an average score of 5, so rep-capping is less likely, unless most of the answers were posted on the same day.

Comment: @Federico Later answers can be zero or negatively-voted; those still count.

Comment: @Federico Following scenario could be possible (although only more diluted versions of it would be plausible): User posts 1 stellar answer which gets 1000 upvotes in a day and then only zero score answers for 200 total.

Comment: Another way this could happen is if an "ordinary" gold-badge 10k+ user suddenly goes off the deep end and starts posting red-flaggable questions. For each post deleted *as* Spam or Rude, there's a -100 rep penalty. Earn a few dozen of those and bam, back down under 10k. It's quite possible that would earn a suspension as well as a question ban, but after the suspension has been served, the user could be a gold badge holder with 2k rep.